# using logical OR operator (a || b) to run one of two function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, logical-operators

why is it that I can only call one of two functions using a ternary operator?

what I'd like to do:

```
newToken(account, request, response, returning = false) {
  /* Irrelevant code ommitted */
    return Promise.resolve((returning || response.json)({message: 'ok', account}))
}
```

the above uses the logical `OR` operator to select the `returning` function if available otherwise just set a json response

however, when I set the code up this way i get an error: `Cannot read 'app' of undefined`

if I use a ternary instead, the code works fine:

```
newToken(account, request, response, returning = false) {
  /* Irrelevant code ommitted */
    return Promise.resolve(returning ? returning({message: 'ok', account}) : response.json({message: 'ok', account}))
}
```

if I just run `console.log((returning || response.json))` the correct function is always logged, so why can't I run the functions when set like this?

Comment: additional info this is using node `8.3.0`, does node use a Proxy on the response object?

Comment: i think `Promise.resolve((returning || response.json)({message: 'ok', account}))` should be this `Promise.resolve(returning || response.json({message: 'ok', account}))`.give it a try

Comment: no, the code is correct. look at the ternary version. the goal is to call one of two functions with the same arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response.json(...)
```

`this` inside the function is equal to the value of `response`.

When you use the `OR` version, it's equivalent to:

```
tempfn = returning || response.json;
tempfn({message: 'ok', account});
```

Calling `tempfn` doesn't bind the `this` variable to anything, so it defaults to the global object.

The `response.json` function presumably needs access to the `response` object, so it fails when you don't bind it correctly.

You can get what you want by calling `.bind()` explicitly:

```
newToken(account, request, response, returning = false) {
  /* Irrelevant code ommitted */
    return Promise.resolve((returning || response.json.bind(response))({message: 'ok', account}))
}
```

Comment: @melpomene Fixed the answer.

Comment: Alternatively: `(returning || function (x) { return response.json(x) })({message: 'ok', account})` or `(returning || x => response.json(x))({message: 'ok', account})`.

Comment: @Barmar that makes sense. I don't think the `bind` is worth the reduced code, so I guess I'll leave it as a ternary

Comment: IMHO, both versions are confusing, I would just write an `if` statement. There's no prize for fitting everything onto one line.

Comment: I'm aware of the reduced legibility, but I don't think it's really that hard to see what's going on anyways

Comment: How about this one: `newToken(account, request, response, returning = x => response.json(x)) { ... return Promise.resolve(returning({message: 'ok', account})); }`

Comment: @melpomene We could go on like this forever, JS has lots of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: @melpomene now that is the stuff of geniuses. I think I even used that in a different function, so I don't know why i didn't think of it

Comment: And ES6 syntax makes it as compact as calling `.bind()`